# how can we parse html into react native view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ckeditor

i am trying to parse simple html into react-native view this is example

```
<p>Hello world <b>world</b> <i>foo</i> abc</p>
```

i have searched alot but unable to find the way of achieving this , i am using ckeditor in react site to enter data i want to show that data into my react native mobile app so that's why i am looking for parsing html into react native web-view , i have tried multiple things but nothing worked for me i have tried

```
import DOMParser from 'react-native-html-parser';
useEffect(() => {
    const html = `<p>Hello world <b>world</b> <i>foo</i> abc</p>`;
    console.log('dom parser ====> ', DOMParser.DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html'))
}, [])
```

but this is not working instead showing an error , is there any way to achieve this thing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

    <WebView
            scalesPageToFit={false}
            style={{flex: 1}}
            source={{html: `<p>Hello world <b>world</b> <i>foo</i> abc</p>`}}
          />
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.